# php datetime createformat parse

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to parse following string:

```
 Thu Oct 03 2013 07:03:41 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Standard Time)
```

But I'm struggling to find the corresponding format, I tried:

```
  $date= DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d Y H:i:s eO (*)','Thu Oct 03 2013 07:03:41 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Standard Time)');
  echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Which results in error. Problem is, that there is no space between GMT+0200 and the brackets. Following works just fine

```
$date= DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d Y H:i:s e O','Thu Oct 03 2013 07:03:41 GMT +0200');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

But (obviously) I should be able to parse also the first example. So do you have any suggestion how the correct format should look like?

the error I get:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in C:\....
```

var_dump of $date before calling $date->format:

```
 boolean false
```

Comment: What error did it give

Comment: what is the error you see? also, are you missing an apostrophe in --> e O',[here?]Thu Oct <---

Comment: yup sorry, ctrl+c ctrl+v typo. I also edited the question with error

Comment: what does var_dump($date) output before calling format() on it?

Comment: false (also added to question)

Comment: Not sure if I'm the only one who is experiencing this, but your code actually doesn't report me any error, but returns this: 2013-10-03

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the format string, which should be

```
D M d Y H:i:s e+
```

I have replaced `eO` with just `e` because the input contains `GMT+0200`, which does *not* have a separator between "GMT" and the offset. I have also replaced the `(*)` part with `+`, which is the only specifier that can consume a variable amount of input (`*` matches one token, i.e. one word -- if there is more input afterwards the parse fails).

Note that there will still be a warning due to the use of `+` (use `DateTime::getLastErrors` to see it), but the conversion will work correctly.

Comment: Could you link to the docs for the use of '+'. I'm probably missing something, but can't find anything atm.

Comment: @vascowhite: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php, bottom of the table.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the incoming string. Here is one way of skinning this particular cat:-

```
$dateString = 'Thu Oct 03 2013 07:03:41 GMT+0200(Central Europe Standard Time)';
\DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d Y H:i:s O', explode('(', $dateString)[0]);
```

See http://php.net/date for more help.

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/NWFVo).

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about the same thing, but trying to avoid that solution :-)

Comment: @user1762087 I can appreciate that. However, this method does avoid generating the warning that Jon's method produces. However, if you are not checking DateTime::getLastErrors() for the warning then that won't be an issue for you.