# DateTime::createFromFormat() with trailing timezone

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am facing some weird issue with [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

I have an input date as

**Fri May 09 2014 11:00:00 GMT 0200**

Now when I apply the DateTime::createFromFormat() on it it does not seems be working.

So here what I did

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M m Y H:i:s T 0200', 'Fri May 09 2014 11:00:00 GMT 0200');
echo $d->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

The above code works well.

Now the issue is I saw that the value 0200 is changing for different input values which usually comes from a feed. And could not find a way to deal with this.

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

In the manual it supports + , * to be added at the end but this gives error

so

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M m Y H:i:s T *', 'Fri May 09 2014 11:00:00 GMT 0200');
Array 
( 
  [warning_count] => 0 
  [warnings] => Array ( ) 
  [error_count] => 1 
  [errors] => Array ( 
     [30] => Trailing data 
  ) 
)
```

The work around I am doing is by removing the last 4 digits and then using the formation as

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M m Y H:i:s T', 'Fri May 09 2014 11:00:00 GMT');
```

But the question is, if there is a proper way to deal with this i.e. without having to replace the last 4 digits and use the input as it is and use the DateTime class to deal with it ?

```
$d = new DateTime('Fri May 09 2014 11:00:00 GMT 0200');
```

also produces the output as

```
DateTime Object 
( 
  [date] => 0200-05-15 11:00:00 
  [timezone_type] => 2 
  [timezone] => GMT 
)
```

I checked these posts

[Convert date string to UTC time with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840978/convert-date-string-to-utc-time-with-php)

[php datetime createformat parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184831/php-datetime-createformat-parse)

and did not help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you [use `+`](http://3v4l.org/punpQ#v539) instead of `*`, it will work as desired. Thsi only works on PHP versions >=5.3.9. It still generates a warning (lord knows why, since you are explicitly allowing trailing data) but it doesn't cause the parse routine to outright fail, and at least it's just an internal warning and not an actual PHP warning.

What causes `*` to fail is that it allows (emphasis mine):

> Random bytes until the next separator **or digit**

Since your trailing data is all digits, the `*` parsing returns immediately without consuming any characters, leaving the string pointer in a position where there are still trailing bytes on the end.

Comment: Ah i see my server is on  on PHP5.3 and perhaps when I was trying with + it also generated nothing for the converted date. Just tried on a different machine and seems to work but yes the warning is still there. Thanks for the answer I was almost going crazy and could not even realize that on PHP 5.3 is does not work and on 5.3.9 it works with the hidden warning. I will accept the answer. Would you mind specifying the version difference may cause this issue to your answer, so that someone else does not have to bang the head like me :)

Comment: Yes now I read the 3v4l output again it looks like this was bug until 5.3.9. I will update this answer - and you should really upgrade your server, 5.3 is now EOL ;-)

Comment: yes I am upgrading right away looks like the distribution package in debian is the latest one wheezy so upgrading PHP. Not sure how on earth old version of PHP is doing on debian. Anyways thanks a lot again.